# Use UISwitch to Show/Hide Image

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, show-hide, uiswitch

I am trying to use a UISwitch to show an image when on, and hide that image when off. I keep running into the issue where the image shows when the switch is turned on but it doesn't hide when the switch is turned off. I've tried a bunch of different solutions online but none seem to work.

This is one of the solutions I've tried. Is there another way to determine if the switch is on aside from switchname.on? Maybe if else statements aren't the way to go?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *spawnImage;


- (IBAction)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

UIImageView *spawnImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 300, 169)];

if(spawnPoints.on){
    NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-spawn.png"]];

}

else{
    NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-none.png"]];

}

[self.view addSubview:spawnImage];
}
```

**Update!**

**Thanks to @meda we figured out a solution.**

.h

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *spawnImage;
}
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
if(spawnPoints.on){
    NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-spawn.png"]];
}

else{
    NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-none.png"]];
}

[self.view addSubview:spawnImage];
}
```

Note that this is an IB solution where a blank UIImageView must be dragged in and position and hooked up to the outlet in connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there another way to determine if the switch is on aside from switchname.on?

Yes you can try `isOn` instead of `on`:

```
   if(spawnPoints.isOn){
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
        [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-spawn.png"]];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
        [spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freight-none.png"]];
    }
```

---

or

```
[spawnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:spawnPoints.isOn?
                    @"freight-spawn.png": @"freight-none.png"]];
```

Comment: Still having same issue, the first image appears on switch change, but it won't hide.

Comment: @Seslyn You need to have `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *spawnPoints;` in your interface file

Comment: Dont forget to attach your control to the Sent Event (Value changed) in your case its `changeSwitch`

Comment: in IB? Yeah its all hooked up with Value Changed for the Action and the IBOutlet as well

Comment: weird so what do you see in the logs ? it never reaches the else block?

Comment: In the logs, it shows that the switch changes from OFF to ON, and then from ON to OFF, but after the ON image appears, it never hides

Comment: You have to check the images because your code is fine, its also case sensitive please double check, you can move that line out of the condition to see if that even change the image

Comment: I tried it with a different image. Basically the images read in fine, they just overlap with each other. The -spawn image won't hide, and neither with the -none with the switch changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43074/discussion-between-meda-and-seslyn)